# How to get HiveContext from JavaSparkContext

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hivecontext

In some Spark codes, I have seen that programmers use such code to create SparkContext

```
 SparkSession session = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Hive Example")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate();
```

But I have always used such kind of code to create JavaSparkContext.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple App").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext spark = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
```

From the latter part of the code, is there any way I could get a Hive Context to perform operations on Hive Tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Also with SparkSession, I cannot use the parallelize() method. Any alternative? I don't seem to understand when to use SparkSession and JavaSparkContext. The Java programming guide by Apache Spark uses both as per their need. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .appName("SampleApp")
                    .master("local")
                    .enableHiveSupport()
                    .getOrCreate();

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spark 2.0 or later which doesn't use `SQLContext` anymore. `SparkSession` with `enableHiveSupport` is a sufficient replacement.

So all you have to do is `session` instance you already have.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently using Spark 2.2.0 and am new to it. Do JavaSparkContext has an advantage over SparkSession? Or JavaSparkContext is going to get depreciated sometime in future?